# Proof of Integral and Limes

Tags: analysis, integration, limits

I need an idea for the following statement:

$f: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous and $x\in (a,b)$ $\implies$  $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y) \, dy = f(x) }$

I just need a start...

Thx for advices

Comment: *Put the **lime** in the coconut and drink it all up...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $$\frac d{dh}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y)dy=f(x-h)+f(x+h)$$
As $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y)dy=\int_{x}^{x}f(y)dy=0$$(continuity of integral), by De L'Hopital,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y)dy=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{2}[(f(x-h)+f(x+h)]=f(x)$$

You should explain why we can integrate over $[x-h,x+h]$

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the limit is for $h>0$.
The general case can easily be adapted.

Observe that
$$
\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y)dy -f(x)=\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}(f(y)-f(x))dy.
$$
It follows that 
$$
| \frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y)dy -f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h}|f(y)-f(x)|dy \leq \sup_{y\in[x-h,x+h]} |f(y)-f(x)|.
$$

Now the result follows directly from the continuity of $f$ at $x$.